# Override styles in media queries with custom CSS

Tags: css, media-queries, css-specificity

I'm writing some `overrides.css` for existing system and want to know what are the ways I can override some styles. I don't have access to system css so I can't rewrite it.

If I have the following definitions in the original system:

```
#criterionDetailsWrapper {
    background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 979px) {
    #criterionDetailsWrapper {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
    #criterionDetailsWrapper {
        background-color: grey;
    }
}
```

How Can I override these styles e.g. to have

I. One property overridden for all dimensions:

```
.criterionDetailsWrapper {
   background-color: grey;
}
```

II. Override one property change to not have 2 break points to but only 1 break point e.g. at `600px`?

```
#criterionDetailsWrapper {
   background-color: grey;
}


 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #criterionDetailsWrapper {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

**Is `!important` the only way to do it, or I need to mimic all selector (to get same specificity) and ensure that my custom CSS is rendered the last?**

Comment: Is the class selector a typo or do you want the rule to apply to all elements with that class, overriding the system rules in the case of elements with that class that also have that id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually media queries **do not make specificity higher**. That's the reason You declare them after the declaration they are modifying. So declaring them in Your css style should be enough, as long as you address all the properties contained in media queries (and their specificity is still the same).

Remember to load `overrides.css` after the styles you want to override.

---

Also the ugly hack (but completely in line with the css specs), alows You to battle specificity by chaining class and id selectors with themselves.

`.class.class` has higher specificty than `.class`, but lower than `.class.class.class`.

It is bad, but may cause less problems than `!important`.

---

In Your case, examples you proposed should work as long as `override.css` comes after the stylesheet(s) You modify.

```
// orginal.css
#criterionDetailsWrapper {
    background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 979px) {
    #criterionDetailsWrapper {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
    #criterionDetailsWrapper {
        background-color: grey;
    }
}
```

would be overwritten by:

```
// override.css
#criterionDetailsWrapper {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

On any screen size it will be `grey` now.

```
// override.css
#criterionDetailsWrapper {
   background-color: grey;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #criterionDetailsWrapper {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

It will have `grey` background now, unless the screen size is up to `600px`, when it will have `blue` color. `979px` and `667px` will be ignored.

---

More on the topic:

[Calculating specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) - W3C spec

Answer (score 2):

I: I will recommend to add as you said specificity inspecting the element, you can make sure that your class will have priority.

```
.parents ....  #criterionDetailsWrapper {
   background-color: grey;
}
```

using !important is a bad practice but still valid...

II: You can't undefine a css media query instead you can overwrite it as your wish

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .parents...  #criterionDetailsWrapper {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

and then define your new media querys

Comment: So copying exact query and altering it or making query more specific will work?

Comment: yes making your query more specific will make your propertys relevant...

Comment: @zmii yes, you can read this https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/  to efficiently override your selectors without using !important. !important can be the only option when you want to overrides inline style or styles injected via javascript, it does not seem to be your case. basicly: last rule with same specifity overides previous